# TFS2012: Can CommonConfiguration support Team based setup on the web access?

Tags: tfs

The boards: **Work/Backlog/product backlog/board**(*the stories/backlogitems*)  and on **Work/board**(*tasks*) can we have different column mappings per teams? Currently the type - value pairs are stored in CommonConfiguration, so it is project based, can we change it to be Team relative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This totally depends on which update you are on (if you are using on-premise TFS). If your TFS deployment is Update 2 or higher - or you are using TFService - you can customize the "Kanban Board" (the board that shows work items on the backlog), link here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/02/01/customizable-kanban-swim-lanes.aspx. This allows you to change the columns, per team, without changing the workflow of work items themselves.

As for the Task board, you can customize it, but only for an entire team project. This must also be done via the CommonConfiguration file.

Comment: We are on Update 2, on-premise. Thank you for the link, but this does not allows me to map different parts of the workflow to different boards. Eg.: a story's life is in two parts: 1. in sprint, 2. regression & upload. I want the first workflow steps to map to the scrum team's board with "Development done" in the last column and map the last workflow steps to the regression & upload team's with "Development done" in their first column. As there is only one CommonConfiguration file per project, I can't do this. Is there any way to use per-team configuration?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The only team-based column configurations that can be done at the moment are for the Kanban board that relates only to work items that exist in the Requirements category (i.e. PBI or Bug for the Scrum process template)